# How to get notified when a QML item's dimensions change?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.15

I understand that I can get to know if the width or height of a QML item changed using the slots `onWidthChanged` and `onHeightChanged`. This is by doing something like below.

import QtQuick 2.12

```
Item {
    id: my_item

    onWidthChanged: {
        if (my_item.visible) {
            console.log("Dimension chnaged")
        }
    }

    onHeightChanged: {
        if (my_item.visible) {
            console.log("Dimension chnaged")
        }
    }
}
```

Above works well. But I am only interested to know if the dimension of my QML item changed. I just need a callback when width or the height changed. I don't need a callback for both.
Is there a QML signal to listen only for a dimension change?

I am using **Qt 5.15.7** commercial version.

Comment: No such signal exists. There's a suggestion to add one for geometry, but that would include x and y: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83050

Comment: Thanks for informing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create a property which is bound to both `width` and `height` and connect a handler to the changed signal of that property:

```
property double dimensions: width * height
onDimensionsChanged: {
   if(my_item.visible)
       console.log("Dimension changed")
}
```

There is a small risk, namely the number won't change when swapping `width` & `height`, but that might be worth it in your situation

Comment: That small risk can be mitigated by changing "dimensions" to be equal to "width / height".

Comment: Ah nice catch. Thanks for pointing out that little risk. Nevertheless this is a smart way to track the dimension change :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments no such signal currently exists by default.

You can create a `size` or `rect` type property and react on that instead though:

```
property size dimensions: Qt.size(width, height)
onDimensionsChanged: console.log("Dimension changed")
```

Here's a WASM example of it working to power an emitter:

https://www.canonic.com/#https://playground.canonic.com/525f6691-fe05-4824-a7f1-574bb8cabd8b/dimension-changed-signal-example